# suppressing apostophe ' with TreeTagger using R library koRpus

Tags: r, nlp

I am using koRpus, which is a R wrapper to the NLP library TreeTagger.
I am processing French language and seeking lemmas.
Problem : the tokenizer phase doesn't output exactly what I want, there is a problem
with apostrophes, which are grouped to the following word

e.g. it outputs "l'oiseau" as a term (rather than "oiseau").

This is my current function call :

```
treetag("mytext.txt", treetagger="manual", lang="fr", 
        sentc.end = c(".", "!", "?", ";", ":","'"), 
        TT.options=list(path="TreeTagger", preset="fr"))
```

Pre-processing (removing the ') the text beforehand with e.g. stringr and passing the resulting string to treetag is hardly an option, as treetag can only accept a file and not a string as its input.

Thx.

Comment: The question is not clear. Also , `treetag` can accept a cha character vector if you set its parameter :`format="obj"`.

Comment: Did you tray to use the treetagger from a console ? something like `echo "l'oiseau " | TreeTagger/tree-tagger-french-utf8`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with french. Adding the tokenizer option "-f" worked for me. Try :

```
treetag("mytext.txt", treetagger="manual", lang="fr", 
    sentc.end = c(".", "!", "?", ";", ":","'"), 
    TT.options=list(path="TreeTagger", preset="fr",tknz.opts="-f"))
```